# Customizing ckeditor to accept html and body tags using yii2-ckeditor-widget

Tags: widget, ckeditor, customization, yii2

I am using 2 amigos ckeditor widget

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'basic'
]) ?>
```

How do I add the configuration settings, I want the editor to accept HTML tags hTML and body which the editor usually stripes off. Where do i specify this setings in the widget.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is special property called `clientOptions` for setting plugin options.

For filtering tags use `allowedContent` option, you can read official docs [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules-section-string-format).

Here is an example of code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'text')->widget(CKEditor::className(), [
    'options' => ['rows' => 6],
    'preset' => 'basic',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'allowedContent' => ...,
    ],
]) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

So i added the configuration `'allowedContent' => true` and it worked.